# PackageInfo.versionName returns INSTANT_RUN in Android Studio 2.2 preview

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently update my android studio to 2.2 preview. When I request for versionName using PackageInfo.versionName it returns INSTANT_RUN instead of actual version name.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the solution? I'm only seeing that with Preview 4. Maybe we should open a bug report for it.

Comment: I downgraded my com.android.tools.build:gradle version to 2.1.2 and it worked.

Comment: Great! Please add that as an answer if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading the com.android.tools.build:gradle version to 2.1.2 worked for me.